# Grails building HQL

Tags: grails, hql

I am using grails 1.3.9 and want to build a query using HQL. The result I should get must be printed like this:

```
com.controllers.global.domain.DomainClassName : 43042
```

and my query currently looks like this:

```
def List = DomainClassName.executeQuery("select a.name from TerminPatient a where a.surname like ?",[searchString.trim()]);
```

Instead of a.name I must put in a star like this *. But it doesn't work. How should I modify my query to get the result like on the top of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select "a"

```
def List = DomainClassName.executeQuery("select a from TerminPatient a where a.surname like ?",[searchString.trim()]);
```